# Images are blurry, loading "smaller" then needed

Tags: magento2, thumbnail

We are having issues with the Upselling Slider. This is the code I use to get the product thumbnails:

```
<?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); ?>
<?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, 'category_page_grid')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE);
$productImageUrl = $productImage->getUrl(); 
echo "<!-- " . $productImageUrl . "-->"; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImageUrl; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
```

This is the result we get:

[image: Blurry image]

The Default code in the `items.phtml` is:

```
 <?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
```

which gives us the same result (I'd say), so I does not depend on the code, as far as I understand this.

How can I load "full" thumbnail images? I understand that this will increase loading times, but the customer wishes to get non-blurry images, which is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by declaring a new value in the `etc/view.xml` and further use it as $image's value.

```
        <image id="slider_image_grid" type="image">
            <width>595</width>
            <height>842</height>
        </image>
```

and PHP:

```
<?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, 'slider_image_grid')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE); ?>
```